# Django change ordering of items in a Postgres ArrayField

Tags: django

```
dm_scripts = ArrayField(models.TextField(blank=True, null=True), default=list)
```

I have a Django model, and I wanted to use the ArrayField to store a list of TextFiles.  The order matters, and I've been asked to allow a user to reorder these.  How would you do that?

I've googled and searched here, but found nothing.  Even Django's official documentation doesn't mention this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I was looking for an answer, found one and thought I'd post the solution in case it is useful to others

A Django Postgres ArrayField is basically a list (at least in your case), so once you access it like `object.dm_scripts` you can manipulate it like any other list. For example, if you need to sort something alphabetically, you can call:

```
ordered_array = sorted(object.dm_scripts)
ordered_array.save()
```

Afterwards the list items will stay in that order. You can call that and apply it anywhere necessary, in a view, a `def save` method or whatever.

After that it's up to your imagination. Implementation would really depend on the UX interaction. I think it would be easy to pass the list to a javascript front-end, have the user reorder them visually, then apply the new order to the list items (Or many surely more optimised methods).